# Google Analytics API(Client library for Python) - Error handling

Tags: python, error-handling, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I am using Batching requests in Google Analytics API(Python). Link to Batching : https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch
Batching works fine when all the records via .add() are correct(valid). When one or more values are invalid, then the batching fails for all the records.

I added a call back function to handle the error and I saw that BAtching request is failing for all the records in the batch ( as opposed to only the invalid record). **Is there a way to handle the error and skip the row/record which is invalid and continue with the rest of the records in the batch?**

Below is the sample code I used and the error message :

```
def add_user_callback(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception:
        print "error :",exception
    else:
        print "successful"

def main():
    ## code to set the account, property and other variables
    batch.add(service.management().webpropertyUserLinks().insert(
        accountId=account_id,
        webPropertyId=property_at,
        body={
                    'permissions': {
                        'local': [
                            'READ_AND_ANALYZE'
                        ]
                    },
                    'userRef': {
                        'email': 'valid_address@domain.com'
                    }
                }))

    batch.add(service.management().webpropertyUserLinks().insert(
        accountId=account_id,
        webPropertyId=property_at,
        body={
                    'permissions': {
                        'local': [
                            'READ_AND_ANALYZE'
                        ]
                    },
                    'userRef': {
                        'email': 'invalid_address@ddomain.com' ## i used a dummy id : pppp@domain.com
                    }
                }))
    batch.execute()


#Error :
#error : <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/62974313/webproperties/UA-62974313-35/entityUserLinks?alt=json returned "Value for field user.email = ppppp@domain.com is not valid.">
#error : <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/62974313/webproperties/UA-62974313-11/entityUserLinks?alt=json returned "Value for field user.email = ppppp@domain.com is not valid.">
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Use the `request_id` in the add method to keep track of the requests that fail, and re-attempt with only those well formatted requests.

The entire batch requests needs to be atomic as it may require multiple requests to change the ACLs of a single user -- imagine the requests required to move a user from the account level to the view level.

Comment: Matt, Could you point to some example code to handle request_id. When there is an exception, I am trying to handle it in a callback function. Here is the code I am using: `bad_email = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*@[a-z]*[.][a-z]*\S',str(exception))
        bad_emails.append(bad_email)
        print "emails in the bad_emails list:",bad_emails[0]
        create_batch(email_list, bad_emails)`                                                                create_batch() here calls the function to create batch( withtout the bad_emails)

Comment: I have added a more complete solution below to help you extract the offending email from response.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a list of users you want to add to profiles stored in a list `users`.
You can remove the bad emails with the following callback function:

```
def call_back(request_id, response, exception):
  if exception is not None:
    if isinstance(exception, HttpError):
      message = json.loads(exception.content)['error']['message']
      bad = 'Value for field user.email = (\S*) is not valid.'
      match = re.match(bad, message)
      if match:
        bad_user = match.group(1)
        if bad_user in users:
          users.remove(bad_user)
  else:
    print response
```

After all the failed calls return you can re-attempt the batch call again by looping through the users and constructing a new batch request:

```
batch = BatchHttpRequest(callback=call_back)
for user in users:
    request = analytics.management().profileUserLinks().insert(
        accountId=ACCOUNT_ID,
        webPropertyId=PROFILE_ID,
        profileId=profile,
        body={
            'permissions': {'local': ['READ_AND_ANALYZE']},
            'userRef': {'email': user}
      }
    )
    batch.add(request, request_id=PROFILE_ID + user)
batch.execute()
```